# Editing the portion of canvas

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to cut the selected portion of bitmap and i have to paste it in the same bitmap  using .. please help me out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by generating an second Bitmap with the portion the user selected. Them to draw, just use the Canvas of the first. It's not so hard.

A tip is: The Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)

This draws a portion of the Bitmap limited by the Rects args.